# Why I am not able to read VarInt field from binary data using protobuf-net

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

everyone,

I am using protobuf-net library to serialize-deserialize text data into binary files. I had similar error in the past but then i made a mistake of writing binary data to a text file. This time i am sure that the file is written in Binary mode. While I read the data, I get **EndOfStream exception: Attempted to read past the end of the stream.**

I have a message header before each object in binary file.

```
message HeaderMessage {
  required double timestamp = 1;
  required string ric_code = 2;
  required int32 count = 3;
  required int32 total_message_size = 4;
}
```

I am getting exception when i am reading total_message_size field at fixed location

```
HEADER: 1111    1       1       hk      0
File: 398909440 bytes
Reading data objects:
1073561: 09 e3 a5 9b c4 0c b3 e0 40 12 07 31 30 39 33 2e 48 4b 18 04 20 5a
1073677: 09 e3 a5 9b c4 0c b3 e0 40 12 07 30 32 39 37 2e 48 4b 18 02 20 2d
1073748: 09 e3 a5 9b c4 0c b3 e0 40 12 07 30 32 39 37 2e 48 4b 18 04 20 5a
1073864: 09 e3 a5 9b c4 0c b3 e0 40 12 07 38 31 37 33 2e 48 4b 18 02 20 2d
1073935: 09 e3 a5 9b c4 0c b3 e0 40 12 07 38 31 37 33 2e 48 4b 18 04 20 5b
1074052: 09 e3 a5 9b c4 0c b3 e0 40 12 07 30 32 33 35 2e 48 4b 18 02 20 2d
1074123: 09 e3 a5 9b c4 0c b3 e0 40 12 07 30 36 30 33 2e 48 4b 18 02 20 2d
1074194: 09 e3 a5 9b c4 0c b3 e0 40 12 07 30 36 30 33 2e 48 4b 18 04 20 5b
1074311: 09 e3 a5 9b c4 0c b3 e0 40 12 07 30 32 33 35 2e 48 4b 18 06 20 8a
```

In the above output, first field is the stream position. Total stream length is 398909440. So its not possible that the stream has reached its end. I tried to print individual fields at the point when it fails to read, I see that the ProtoReader class is always failing to read total_message_size field.

In aboe output, the last row is the culprit where protobuf-net is not able to read the data.

```
1074311: 09 e3 a5 9b c4 0c b3 e0 40 12 07 30 32 33 35 2e 48 4b 18 06 20 8a
```

If we split the fields, the data looks as follows:

```
field1 timestamp field: type: 09  payload: e3 a5 9b c4 0c b3 e0 40
field2 ric_code field: type: 12   payload: 07 30 32 33 35 2e 48 4b
field3 count field:    type: 18   payload: 06
field4 total_message_size: type: 20 payload: 8a
```

the exception is raised while reading the payload of 4th field and the value is 8a. (decimal 138).

Stack trace is as follows:

```
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.TryReadUInt32VariantWithoutMoving(Boolean trimNegative, UInt32& value) in C:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\ProtoReader.cs:line 101
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadUInt32Variant(Boolean trimNegative) in C:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\ProtoReader.cs:line 138
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadInt32() in C:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\ProtoReader.cs:line 264
   at protobuf_test.Program.Main(String[] args) in H:\Personal\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\protobuf-test\protobuf-test\Program.cs:line 80
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

what is the issue in reading the value 138? What is the issue in this case?

Regards,
Alok

Comment: Thank you for including enough information to give a considered answer, but this appears to be an issue with the *writer* (which IIRC is C++ in your case), rather than the *reader* (protobuf-net)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

0x8a is **not** a valid varint. Varint encoding uses the MSB as a continuation bit, meaning: if the MSB is set, there is at least one more byte expected (it continues until the MSB is **not** set, combining the remaining 7-bit chunks little-endian style). Consequently, 0x8a **cannot** exist by itself in a valid varint. 0x8a **and something else**, *sure*. You can see this in the [wire spec](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/encoding.html#varints). Please ensure you haven't accidentally cut the end off this individual message, or misreported the length (since I gather each record is individually wrapped with a size prefix).

Comment: Thanks Marc. I was reporting incorrect header length while writing the header length. Basically I put header length in binary data and then before writing the actual header message, i updated one of the header values which must have changed the header length.